# (LwIP) socket send() returns "Connection already in progress"

Tags: sockets, send, lwip

I'm maintaining an embedded system that uses LwIP. The relevant code is as follows (edited):

```
iobSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
connectRC = connect(socket, &serverAddress, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
FD_SET(socket, &fdset);
selectRC = select((socket) + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv);
sendRC = send(iobSocket, dout, strlen(dout), 0);
```

This seems to work. When I remove the select() call, however, I get an error on the send() which sets errno to 119 or Connection already in progress. This error code isn't documented in the send() man pages.

Can someone tell me why the select() command is even necessary here, and why I might be getting an undocumented error without it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 119 is `EINPROGRESS`. It means the socket is operating in **non-blocking mode** <sup>1</sup>, and the previous `connect()` operation hasn't finished yet, which is why the `send()` fails.

<sup>1</sup>: Which means, there must be more code that you are not showing, as sockets are normally in **blocking mode** when they are initially created, and require explicit code to put them into non-blocking mode, such as via `fcntl(F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);`.

Using `select()` to test the socket for writability allows your code to wait until the socket is actually done connecting and is ready for sending.

This is explained in the [man page for `connect()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> If the connection or binding succeeds, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and `errno` is set to indicate the error.
>
> ERRORS
>
> The following are general socket errors only.  There may be other domain-specific error codes.
>
> ...
>
> `EINPROGRESS`
> **The socket is nonblocking** and the connection cannot be completed immediately.  (UNIX domain sockets failed with EAGAIN instead.)  **It is possible to `select(2)` or `poll(2)` for completion by selecting the socket for writing.**  After `select(2)` indicates writability, **use `getsockopt(2)` to read the `SO_ERROR` option at level `SOL_SOCKET` to determine whether `connect()` completed successfully** (`SO_ERROR` is zero) or unsuccessfully (`SO_ERROR` is one of the usual error codes listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, do I correctly understand that connect() isn't a fully synchronous function? Also, when using select() for this particular purpose, it would seem that the returned value of select() doesn't really matter (as long as it's >=0) -- is this correct?

Comment: @mzimmers "*connect() isn't a fully synchronous function?*" - if the socket is set to **blocking mode** (the default), then `connect()`, `accept()`, `send()`, `recv()`, etc will act *synchronously* on that socket. If the socket is set to **non-blocking** mode, then the functions will act *asynchronously* on that socket. "*the returned value of select() doesn't really matter*" - the return value simply indicates how many sockets are still in the `fd_set`s upon output. But you can't use it for looping through the `fd_set`s, for instance.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for clearing that up - that feature of connect() wasn't at all obvious in the man pages.

Comment: @mzimmers really? I literally quoted the `connect()` man page that explains it.

Comment: Yeah, well..."obvious" is a relative term. There's a lot in the world that isn't obvious to me. In any event, your explanation was a lot clearer.

Comment: so, should I have a similar select() call for my send() and recv() calls as well?

Comment: @mzimmers if the socket is *non-blocking*, then yes. If there is no data to read, `recv()` will fail with `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`, so you can use `select()` or `(e)poll()` beforehand to detect when there is data actually present before trying to read it. If `send()` can't write (because the peer has no buffer space), it will fail with `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`, and you need to use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to detect when the peer has cleared up buffer space before sending again.